# How to change object's pivot point using C# in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the Pivot Point of an object in Unity 3D using C#.

I am aware of editing the object in a design software beforehand to desired point but, in my specific situation,  the Pivot Point needs to be changed while game in running.

Here is the code I am using to rotate the object from its left side:

```
    verticalInputLeft = Input.GetAxis("VerticalLeft");       

    rotationLeftX += verticalInputLeft * verticalSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    rotationLeftX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationLeftX, minAngle, maxAngle);

    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationLeftX, transform.localEulerAngles.y, transform.localEulerAngles.z);
```

I would like to use same method to apply rotation from right side. For that, I need to change the pivot point of the object while game is running.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to change pivots directly,

Workaround, create an empty game object(s) in position of where you want your new pivot and set the parent transform to this game object.

```
gameObject.transform.SetParent(pivotGameObject);
```

to remove parent

```
gameObject.transform.SetParent(null);
```

Comment: Second this. Don't waste time with pivot points or orbits ever. Just parent and lerp.

Comment: @JoelStransky So, I am just going to jump from one parent to other every time. Yes?

Comment: Yes, just think of the parent as a placeholder for pivot point, if it already has a parent just keep a reference to the original parent in void Start() { parentObject = transform.parent; }

Comment: `There is no way to change pivots directly,` not true as it stands ;) Of course you can recalculate a new position for all mesh vertices => new pivot position .. question is when would you want to do such a thing ;)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a way to change pivots.

If you take the RectTransform component directly, you could change the pivot's value and other attributes related to the screen's position.

Example:

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
//Center the pivot
```

Comment: This does not really change the pivot and will not let you adjust anchoredposition dynamically with the changed pivot. Below answer is the correct one.

Comment: To clarify: The pivot itself will change but this will have no effect on the anchoredPosition, even though when changing pivot the inspector will adapt, the anchoredPosition will not.