# How can I make a rocket pivot around it's bottom part insted of the middle in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would I go about making a rocket player controller rotate around its bottom part?

Heres my code up until now (I know it has problems, it's just a proof of concept for now)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ProcessInput();
    }

    private void ProcessInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 2));
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to google for "unity change pivot point" than creating a whole new question there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news, Unity has

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

but! more usefully, it has:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

I'm pretty sure that's exactly what you want.

(BTW be aware - it's not that trivial to figure out just what the vector you rotate around will be.  You have to have a really good feel for cross products and other Vector manipulation.  Unity is annoying like that - it seems really easy to use at first, but you really need a superb grasp of physics (I mean Newtonian physics) and every aspect of vectors and quaternions to really be able to make games - it's tough.)

One tip: you see how you are adding force to move it. Try adding torque (`AddTorque`) to turn it!

Comment: THANK YOU! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Careful with these though! You should never mix the physics (Rigidbody) with any transforms via the `Transform` component as this will break the physics and collision detection and will often behave strange

Comment: Right!  notice the last sentence in the answer, @YuvalAmir

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Rigidbody` you should not mix in movements via `transform`! This breaks the physics and collision detection and leads to strange behavior.

---

rather use e.g. [`Rigidbody.centerOfMass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html) to set the center of mass according to your needs.

And then [`AddTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) or [`MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html)

```
private void ProcessInput()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            turnLeft = true;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            turnRight = true;
        }
    }
}

private bool turnLeft;
private bool turnRight;

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if(turnLeft)
    {
        turnLeft = false;
        rigidbody.MoveRotation(rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidbody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 2));
    }

    if(turnRight)
    {
        turnRight = false;
        rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidbody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -2));
    }
}
```

Though in general it is easier to use an angle per second like e.g.

```
rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidbody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -45 * Time.deltaTime));
```

`Time.deltaTime` is the time passed since the last physics update so this makes sure you rotate with exactly `-45° / second`.

---

Alternatively take a look at [How to change objects pivot point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990806/how-to-change-objects-pivot-point-using-c-sharp-in-unity) -> You could simply put your mesh under a parent object and instead use that parent as the rigidbody and move script etc. so you can create any offset relative to the parent you wish.

And yes one also could recalculate the mesh vertex positions themselves to fit your needs but usually the parenting approach is already sufficient ;)